# Can I create a temporary reference to a struct instance in a method body?

Tags: c#, .net

I know you can pass references to a `struct` in a method, e.g

```
void method(ref MyStruct param)
```

But can I do it within a method body to alias a struct for readability? I had code using this temp var:

```
var properties = this.document.header.protocols[0].properties;
```

It was only when trying to track a bug that I realised it was because it was a struct not a class and I was creating a copy not a reference!

Comment: You may use [ref struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#ref-struct) and [ref returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) for that. They are available from C# 7.0 and 7.2

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski interesting but I would rather not modify the datatype itself. It's a valid answer though I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [starting with C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#ref-locals-and-returns), [ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#ref-locals) are supported:

```
ref var properties = ref this.document.header.protocols[0].properties;
```

Comment: does this care if the original object is a reference or value type?

Comment: "Cannot initialize a by-reference variable with a value" - I believe I am running C# 7.3, .Net framework 4.6.1; is your answer definitely correct (if so I have some other problem!)

Comment: @Mr.Boy note that you need to put `ref` on both sides of the assignment. Your error is typically due to not including `ref` on the RH.

Comment: @Mr.Boy: It works with reference types as well: `var a = "abc"; ref var b = ref a; b = "def"; Console.WriteLine(a);` prints `"def"`.